# Questions about using ssh and how it relates to users

Tags: ssh

I don't really understand how SSH works.

1. When I generate an ssh key on a machine, does this generate a key for the 'entire' machine and all of its users, or just the user i generated the key from?   `ssh-keygen`
2. When you generate an ssh key, does this automatically set ssh to require the use of this key to connect to that machine with that user?
3. I am attempting to use VisualHostKey. Is there a way you can enable it from the CLI without editing /etc/ssh/ssh_config. For example: `ssh -o VisualHostKey=yes` doesn't seem to work

I generated an ssh key on a CentOS test machine in a vm; however, when checking etc/ssh/  I don't see a key for the username I was using at the time, but I do see something for ssh_host_ecdsa  and ssh_host_ed25555; what are those?

Comment: 2. For that user. 3. Nope. No requirements.

Comment: Your keys are generated in `~/.ssh/`, because they are yours.

Comment: 1. No.  Requests for learning material will just get your question closed.

Comment: And for the last question, they are host keys, as described in manual pages and else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can you point me to a good resource to better understand ssh (other than manual pages or pinfo)

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell), [RFCs](http://www.openssh.com/specs.html)

> When I generate an ssh key on a machine, does this generate a key for the 'entire' machine and all of its users, or just the user i generated the key from? ssh-keygen

The key is *file* just as each other. It depends only on you where you place that file and which permissions you will set to it. But it is good practice to leave the file *for you only*. Such as you do with your password, PIN or keys to your home.

> When you generate an ssh key, does this automatically set ssh to require the use of this key to connect to that machine with that user?

No

> I am attempting to use VisualHostKey. Is there a way you can enable it from the CLI without editing /etc/ssh/ssh_config. For example: ssh -o VisualHostKey=yes doesnt seem to work

```
ssh -o VisualHostKey=yes host
```

works. Also you can create your per-user config file in `~/.ssh/config`, where you can store

```
VisualHostKey yes
```

Comment: ++ The RFCs are a good read.

Answer (score 0):

1. Not in the charter of this community or any other stackexchange branch for that matter. Google is your best friend. There are plenty of sites explaining what ssh does, in varying depth of details. Only you can judge what is the right amount of information for you
2. `ssh-keygen` generates keys for the user who invokes it.
3. it is not a requirement but when you start an ssh session, ssh looks for a private key in $HOME/.ssh directory, in the order of rsa key then dsa key as far as I know, but you can tell ssh to not look for this location but some other place or tell not to look for keys at all
4. I have no idea / never used, a visual key. So, I am not sure what to say here